# What does this notation mean, which looks like direct sum?

Tags: group-theory, modules

I ran across this notation in a paper. What does $ Z^{\bigoplus n(n-1)}$ mean? I knew that $ Z^n$ or $ Z^{(n)} $ means direct sum, but never met this one.

Comment: I think it is direct sum, $A^{\oplus 3}= A\oplus A\oplus A$, I have meet this in one of my abstract algebra book

Answer (score 1):

It also means direct sum. The reason this notation exists is that if $I$ is an infinite index set, $Z^I$ should mean the direct *product* of an $I$-indexed family of copies of $Z$, which is different from the direct sum.